In X-Men '97, Season 1, Episode 10, what did Professor X do to Magneto's mind?
Warning! Spoilers ahead!
The question refers to X-Men '97 Season 1 Episode 10.

 After Prof. X takes control over Magneto's mind he somehow restores it, but it is unclear if he (1) erased Magneto's painful memories and personality completely and on this "clean slate" wrote a peaceful Magneto, or (2) restored Magneto's mind without erasing his personality and memories and managed to convince him to save Earth from his own free will (without forcing it on him).

My question is which option - (1) or (2) - is the correct or more plausible one.
